# jQuery function doesn't get defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header

I want to use [this jQuery Zoom libary](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/):

As you can see here on my [example page](https://radlvoo.de/produkt/centurion-backfire-pro-100-27-2017-rh-groesse-33/), I embedded the `jquery.zoom.js` in the head of my page as also jQuery. But I still get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).zoom is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):77)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

Why is that and how can I solve this?

I want to make a magnifier at the product img which has is surrounded by the class `img-wrapper-inner`.

This is how my script looks at the moment:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var img ="<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full', false ); echo $src[0]; ?>";
            jQuery('img-wrapper-inner').zoom({
                url: img, 
                callback: function(){
                    jQuery(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

I would be very thankful for help!
Kind regards

Comment: Did you include the js lib at first of your header page?

Comment: maybe you can move it at the footer for best performance

Comment: Nearly, above the jQuery and the jQueryZoom is only this: `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="wG8pQHzSyDw4DSXa1xZsYHbHf7vKWiZdoKIobnMyamI" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Before I want to optimze the performance I want to get it working..

Comment: Add `<script src="path_to_your_jquery.zoom.min.js"/>` this line after `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Also, please check that you have not used dot(.) for your class i.e. jQuery('.img-wrapper-inner').zoom ...

Comment: My head looks like this. So, it is like you mean @AtaurRahmanMunna. Isn't it?

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/jquery.zoom.js'></script>`

Comment: I don't use a dot (.) as you can see on the code above!

Comment: Please to catch handler by class name in jquery you should use dot (`.`). as already @Kashyap said. e.g `jQuery('.img-wrapper-inner')`

Comment: Doesn't work either!

Comment: Ok, let's open the browser console and see if any errors shown, something like `404 : not found your jquery.zoom.js`. It's clear that, your error `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).zoom is not a function` tell that your library wasn't found in the path you provided in the code.

Comment: No, I don't see any 404! Check the consol by yourself. This is the reason why I linked the website. You can check it by clicking on example page above!

Comment: Could you provide any fiddle ?

Comment: Try to give the CDN version instead of your relative path and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading jQuery twice, on lines 5 and 148 of your code. You load `jquery.zoom.js` on line 6, so it gets stored in the original `jQuery` variable. When you reload jQuery later, it replaces the variable and you lose `jquery.fn.zoom`.

Get rid of the lines at the beginning and load `jquery.zoom.js` in the same block with all the other scripts further down.

Comment: Thank You! I fixed it now by deregistering the jQuery from WordPress and using the Google CDN jQuery. But now I have one error left. It is this one `(index):82 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).colorbox is not a function
    at HTMLImageElement.callback ((index):82)
    at HTMLImageElement.img.onload (jquery.zoom.js:225)`

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use the WP or CDN version of jQuery, as long as you just load it once before loading any plugins. I don't see that error when I load your site, do I have to do something to trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem. See the example I made for you.

```js
jQuery(function(){
    $('.img-wrapper-inner').zoom({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://radlvoo.de/jquery.zoom.js"></script>
<span id="example" class="img-wrapper-inner">
    <img class="photo" width='100' height='100' src = "http://oi67.tinypic.com/2n7m7v4.jpg"/>
</span>
```

If you want to url as an options, then code will be like

```js
jQuery(function(){
    $('.img-wrapper-inner').zoom({
 url:'http://oi67.tinypic.com/2n7m7v4.jpg'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://radlvoo.de/jquery.zoom.js"></script>
<span id="example" class="img-wrapper-inner">
  <img class="photo" width='100' height='100' src = ""/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to add your jQuery version but it is giving error of `extend`

`<script src="https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>`

So suggestion is try to add this library and than check

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var img ="https://radlvoo.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Backfire_Pro_100_29_Petrol_MY2017.png";

    jQuery('.img-wrapper-inner').zoom({
      url: img
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
<div class="img-wrapper-inner">
<img height="300" width="400" src="https://radlvoo.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Backfire_Pro_100_29_Petrol_MY2017-360x229.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here, Something else in your code is causing the problem.

```js
var img = "https://radlvoo.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Backfire_Pro_100_29_Petrol_MY2017.png";
$(".img-wrapper-inner img").attr("src", img);


$('.img-wrapper-inner').zoom({
  url: img,
  callback: function() {
    // jQuery(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
  }
});
```

```css
.img-wrapper-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.img-wrapper-inner img{
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://radlvoo.de/jquery.zoom.js"></script>

<div class="img-wrapper-inner"><img src=""></div>
```